# Where to set the callback url for realtime subscriptions in a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a new facebook app. And with the new app structure I can't find where to specify the callback url for the app. I used the old apps and there was a section that asks you to choose how facebook interacts with your website and you just specify the callback url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to do this via the Graph API now. Have a look at the

```
POST /{app-id}/subscriptions
```

endpoint (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/subscriptions#publish).

The process of using Realtime Updates is described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1#subscribing

Comment: thanks. I'm just facing a problem with the app access token. i tried the method the docs provided but always get this error: 

'Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: endpoint","type":"OAuthException","code":803'

@Tobi

Comment: So, what's your request url then?

Comment: thanks man i solved it, it was a missing piece in the link. thanks a lot again :)